# How to add certificate to Cacerts file without administrative access?

Tags: java, security, certificate, classpath

I have installed Java to the default folder under a Windows environment.

Yet, I don't have the admin access. How Can I add security certificate to the cacerts file in the `jre/lib/security` path? If editing this file is not possible, Can I copy the cacerts file to another location and can I add it to the classpath?

Comment: It isn't reached via the CLASSPATH.

Comment: @rakesh raki, did below answer helped you?

Answer (score 6):

Copy the existing files to your home directory(or any preferred location), add your certificate to this newly copied accepts file using `keystore` utility.
Once the above step is done, use -D [system](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29585_01/PlatformServices.61x/security/src/csec_ssl_jsp_start_server.html) variables while executing your JVM.

Comment: What a great and simple answer, answered just an hour after asked. I am wondering why it is not accepted... It's not so polite from asking man. Anyway, it helped me today, thank you!

Comment: Not sure about @rakesh raki , It definitely help me